# python cmd 3rd sub level not exiting

Tags: python

I am working on some code from this recipy http://code.activestate.com/recipes/280500/

The EPP code (only the import) I got from github user jochem code: Python-EPP (just to be clear, I did not create the EPP code my self)

I added

```
def do_A_register(self, args):
    i = A_register()
    i.cmdloop()
```

which leads me to:
(edit: Formatting got screwed up)

```
class A_register(cmd.Cmd):
   prompt = "(A register) "
   def do_handles(self, args):
       # Goto sub command
       i = A_registerHandles()
       i.prompt = self.prompt[:-1]+'-> handles $ '
       i.cmdloop()

   def do_domain(self, args):
       # Goto sub command
       pass

   def do_exit(self, args):
       return True

   def do_EOF(self, args):
       return self.do_exit(args)
```

if I do quit or crtl-D in this sub menu I go back 1 level which is want I want but if I go 1 level up to handles (level 2) I cannot go back to level 1 (where level 0 is the shell)

The 3rd level code is this

```
class A_registerHandles(cmd.Cmd):
config = {
    'host': 'epp.a_registar.com',
    'port': 700,
    'user': '<username>',
    'pass': '<password>',
    'handle': '<defaultHandle>',
}

def do_handleAvailable(self, args):
    print "Give handle:",
    handle = raw_input().strip()
    self.epp = EPP(**self.config)
    self.contact = Contact(self.epp, handle)
    canCreate = self.contact.available()
    if bool(canCreate):
        print "Handle %s is free to use." % handle
    else:
        print "Handle %s is in use!" % handle

def do_handleInfo(self, args):
    print "Give handle: ",
    handle = raw_input().strip()
    self.epp = EPP(**self.config)
    self.contact = Contact(self.epp, handle)
    handleInfo = self.contact.info()

def do_exit(self, args):
    return True

def do_EOF(self, args):
    return self.do_exit(args)
```

So I would like to know how to return from level 2 to level 1 (or level 3 to 2 or 4 to 3, you catch my drift)

I created a working example that is returning from level 2 to level 1 but not from 3 to 2.
Due to the length I added the code to pastebin http://pastebin.com/qjF4LPXZ

The python version I am running:

> Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
>   [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2

Thnx for any response.
Paul.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out what problem you are facing ... using your example code I am able to do what I think you are asking. What sequence of events causes the problem?

Comment: From my shell I do: python StackOverflow.py in that (sub) shell I do "A_register" then I get "(A register)" if I do crtl+d I get "=>>' which I want. If I am in (A register) and type handles I get "(A register)-> handles $" and if I the do crtl+d here I get "(A register)-> handles $ (A register)" and when I hit enter I get "(A register)-> handles $" again where I should have got "(A register)"

Comment: No solution ... but I can tell you that by overriding the `parseline()` function I was able to see that after exiting the `do_handles()` function there is a call to `parseline()` with an empty line and then again with "handles" as the line. This is why it keeps going back into the handles prompt after hitting enter. But still not sure _why_ that is happening.